# solve : $3^{\log_3 \sqrt{(x-1)}} < 3^{\log_3{(x-6)}} + 3 $

Tags: logarithms

- **Prove That:** $$ 3^{\log_3\sqrt {x-1}} <3^{\log_3{(x-6)}} + 3 $$
- **My Try At It**: I first took the 3 common and then converted the whole question $$ 3^{\log_3\sqrt {(x-1)}} <3^{\log_3{(x-6)}} + 3 $$ 
  into a logarithamic one but at the end I got stuck.

Comment: Do you know that $3^{\log_3 a}=a$?

Comment: thanks for it. i forgot bout that one

Comment: I particularly loved the "my try at it" part !

Comment: is it $$3^{\log_3 x-6}$$ or $$3^{\log_3 (x-6)}$$?

Comment: i solved it. thanks. the second one is correct

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay I edited your post. Is this what you meant?